# What MySQL statement needed to populate a field with incremental number

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I have an old MS Access DB which I'm translating to a MySQL DB. I used bullzip to create the database but due to bad design the old MS Access database didn't have a unique primary key for most of the tables.

So I've created a id field but obviously it's empty for each entry, I wonder if there's a simple statement I can use to fill them up with 1, 2, 3, 4 etc...

**EDIT:**
I think I haven't gotten my question across properly. I know all about auto increment. Thats not the problem.

I have a table, full of records which I need kept and which came from a Access database that didn't have a unique id defined as a field. In otherwords I have fields for firstname, surname etc etc but no field 'id'. This seems absolutely crazy but apparently this database has been well used and never had any unique ids for any tables bar one. Weird!

Anyway, I've created a field in the table for id (and set it to auto increment of course) but obviously all the existing records don't have an id set currently. So I need to create one for each record.

Is there a way to fill all these records with unique numbers using a mysql statement?

Cheers

Comment: check my update solution and let me know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add an new id column to an existing table and make it AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, it will automatically populate it with incrementing values.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE TheTable ADD COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
mysql> SELECT id FROM TheTable;
-- outputs values 1, 2, 3, etc.
```

If you made an id column but didn't declare it AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, you can populate the column like this:

```
mysql> SET @id := 0;
mysql> UPDATE TheTable SET id = (@id := @id+1);
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks for the help! Works a treat

Answer (score 2):

Use a predefined AUTO_INCREMENT field, and set the value as NULL when inserting new records, so that it automatically builds up an appropriate incrementer. Aside from that, there is no way (unless using a procedure) to create an incrementing set of values

Answer (score 0):

Use the auto_increment feature of MySQL. MySQL will generate unique numbers for your id column.

For an explanation of the auto_increment feature see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
CREATE TABLE insect
    (
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    origin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    );
```

**Update**

I believe, it seems tough task unless you won't create new table, I will suggest you to use this

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, itemID FROM orders;
```

It will create a virtual column with the name `rank` for you, which have unique id value.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a unique identifier, you can use the `uuid()` function.  It takes up a bit more space than an integer, but it does what you want.

However, I agree with the other answers that you should add an auto increment column and repopulate the table.  That is the simplest way to keep the ids unique over time, even as updates takes place, and using a more reasonable amount of storage.

Answer (score 0):

I am not proficient in MySQL, but I have faced this same problem in other DBMS's and here is how I have addressed it when there was an AutoIncrement type facility, but the DBMS had no way to automatically apply it retroactively:

1. Rename the table you want to add the ID field to.  So rename Table1 to Table1_Old.
2. Create a new Table1 that is a copy of Table1_Old except that it has no data in it.
3. Add your ID/AutoIncrement column to Table1
4. Now copy all of the data from Table1_Old to Table1, either skipping or specifying NULL for the ID column. (This is usually a single INSERT..SELECT.. command)
5. Drop Table1_Old.

The actual specifics and commands vary from DBMS to DBMS, but I have usually been able to find a way to do these steps.